# adaptivethreshold gives an error (opencv, java)

Tags: java, opencv, adaptive-threshold

I am trying to do adaptiveThresholding on an image but it gives me this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1) in adaptiveThreshold
```

I can't seem to understand why, here is my code:

```
         Mat source = Highgui.imread("camera.jpg", 
         Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         Imgproc.cvtColor(source, destination, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

         Highgui.imwrite("grayscale.jpg", destination);

         Mat source2 = Highgui.imread("grayscale.jpg", 
         Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

         Mat destination2 = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(source2, destination2, 255,
         Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 4);
```

Comment: Please update the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: I am new here, so i don't really know what you mean by that.

Comment: A stacktrace is shown, when an uncaught exception occurs. It tells you the line of code, where the exception was inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [adaptiveThreshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold) source should be 8-bit single-channel image, but you are loading `source2` as colour,

So, Change the line

```
 Mat source2 = Highgui.imread("grayscale.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

to

```
 Mat source2 = Highgui.imread("grayscale.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Also why to save and load `destination` image before adaptiveThreshold,  pass it directly  to  `adaptiveThreshold()`